# Finding query in substring instead of full text

Tags: php, forms, mysqli, substring

I have created a search function. It can find address by the full text but how do I go about to make the query search by parts of the address ? For e.g. the full address is `paya lebar Road Blk27`, how do I make it so that the user can just type in `paya` and it would still show up ?

**SearchForm**

```
<h2>View Patient Records</h2>


<body>
<form action="display_patient.php" method="post">
<p>Select:
<select name="patient_var" >
<?php 
$value = array(view_all, name, address); 
foreach ($value as $option)
{
    echo '<option value="'.$option.'"' . (isset($_POST['patient_var']) && $_POST['patient_var'] == $option ? ' selected' : '') . '>' . $option . '</option>';
}

?>
</select>

<input type="text" name="typed" value="" />

<input type ="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</p>

<p>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['patient_var'])) {

    $type = $_POST['typed'];
    $select = $_POST['patient_var'];
 if ($select == 'view_all') {
     echo "<table border='1'>"; 
 echo "<tr>\n"; 
echo "<th>ID</th>\n"; 
echo "<th>Patient Name</th>\n"; 
echo "<th>Age</th>\n";
echo "<th>NRIC</th>\n";
echo "<th>Birth Date</th>\n";
echo "<th>Medical Allergies</th>\n";
echo "<th>Medical History</th>\n";
echo "<th>Phone</th>\n";
echo "<th>Address</th>\n";
echo "<th>Doctor Assigned</th>\n";
 echo "</tr>"; 

    $pat_set = default_patient();

     while ($mo = mysqli_fetch_array($pat_set)) {
                echo "<tr>"; 
 echo "<td>" . $mo['id'] . "</td>"; 
 echo "<td>". $mo['name'] . "</td>"; 
  echo "<td>". $mo['age'] . "</td>"; 
   echo "<td>". $mo['nric'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>". $mo['birthdate'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>". $mo['medical_allergies'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>". $mo['medical_history'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>". $mo['phone'] . "</td>";     
 echo "<td>". $mo['address'] ."</td>"; 
        echo "<td>". $mo['doctor_assigned'] . "</td>";
 echo "</tr>"; 
            }
 } 




else {
    echo "<table border='1'>\n"; 
echo "<tr>\n"; 
echo "<th>ID</th>\n"; 
echo "<th>Patient Name</th>\n"; 
echo "<th>Age</th>\n";
echo "<th>NRIC</th>\n";
echo "<th>Birth Date</th>\n";
echo "<th>Medical Allergies</th>\n";
echo "<th>Medical History</th>\n";
echo "<th>Phone</th>\n";
echo "<th>Address</th>\n";
echo "<th>Doctor Assigned</th>\n";
 echo "</tr>";

  $patients_set = 
 find_patients($select, $type);

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($patients_set)) 
 { echo "<tr>"; 
 echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>"; 
 echo "<td>". $row['name'] . "</td>"; 
  echo "<td>". $row['age'] . "</td>"; 
   echo "<td>". $row['nric'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>". $row['birthdate'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>". $row['medical_allergies'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>". $row['medical_history'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>". $row['phone'] . "</td>";     
 echo "<td>". $row['address'] ."</td>"; 
        echo "<td>". $row['doctor_assigned'] . "</td>";
 echo "</tr>"; }

}  

}//end of if post submit

?>
</p>
```

Comment: use `LIKE %%` in sql query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mysql For searching whether a column has specific string use [LIKE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

Example

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%somestring%';
```

In your case just try this

```
$typed = $_POST['typed'];
```

and make Mysql query like this

```
$query = "select * from table where Address LIKE '%".$typed."%' ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `LIKE '%$searchParam%'` instead of `= $searchParam`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to post your function: find_patients($select, $type);
But I guess you need a partial string query for an address varchar field which looks something like this:

```
select * from MyTable where myColumn like '%myPartialString%';
```

This type of query will return all rows that have "MyPartialString" within.